# VBA Excel: Workbooks.open method works only sometimes

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm developing a quite complex system. I'm using a lot of Workbooks but the ones that envolve my problem are basically: a calendar for all apartments, a contract and a reservation list. From the reservation list I'm creating a contract and before saving that contract, I fill the period in the calendar. When i try to open the Calendar nothing happens and it returns nothing, !BUT THIS PROBLEM ONLY HAPPENS, WHEN THE CONTRACT WAS OPENED BY THE RESERVATION LIST!, when i manually fill and save the contract it works normally, it opens the calendar fine and return its object.

FillContractFromReservations()

```
Public Sub CriarContratoR(data_i As Date, data_f As Date, diaria As Long, inquilino As String, txlimp As Long, pgto As Long, dtpgto As Date, edificio As String, apto As String, id_r As Integer)
    path = "\\MICRO01\Meus documentos\CENTRAL DE ARQUIVOS\2. ALUGUEL\2.1 CONTRATOS ALUGUEL\ALUGUEL DE TEMPORADA\TEMPORADA 2017-2018\Contratos 2017-2018\" & edificio & " " & apto & "\" & edificio & " " & apto & ".xlsm"
    Set contrato = Workbooks.Open(path)
    contrato.Worksheets.Add
    i = contrato.Worksheets.Count()
    With contrato.Worksheets(i)
        .Range("C7").Value = inquilino
        .Range("F24").Value = data_i
        .Range("K24").Value = data_f
        .Range("E27").Value = diaria
        .Range("E28").Value = txlimp
        If pgto <> 0 Then
            .Range("E30").Value = pgto
            .Range("G30").Value = dtpgto
        End If
        .Range("K3").Value = id_r
    End With

    contrato.Worksheets(i).Name = inquilino
    contrato.Save
    contrato.Close
end sub
```

Contract_beforeSave()

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Unprotect Password:="ronryb"
    Dim calendario As Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Set calendario = Workbooks.Open("\\MICRO01\Meus documentos\CENTRAL DE ARQUIVOS\2. ALUGUEL\2.1 CONTRATOS ALUGUEL\ALUGUEL DE TEMPORADA\TEMPORADA 2017-2018\Sistema\02. Calendário 2017-2018.xlsm")'This is the method that works only sometimes
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim edificio, apto As String
    edificio = WB.Worksheets("Liquidação").Range("C3").Value
    apto = WB.Worksheets("Liquidação").Range("H3").Value

    Dim c_row As Integer
    i = 8
    While edificio <> calendario.Worksheets("Imoveis Aluguéis").Cells(i, 2).Value Or apto <> calendario.Worksheets("Imoveis Aluguéis").Cells(i, 3).Value
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    c_row = i
    ... THE CODE GOES ON
```

I'm quite lost, searched a lot and found nothing conclusive. I think this might be an excel bug, but maybe i'm wrong. Sorry for my bad english, any doubts i can explain it better on comments, Thanks!

Comment: I noticed a day or two ago that, if a workbook is already open when you try to do a `Set xyz = Workbooks.Open("the already opened workbook")`, the `xyz` object in my example would be set to refer to `ThisWorkbook`.  Is that possibly related to your issue?

Comment: What is *contrato* after `Set contrato = Workbooks.Open(path)` ? Is it nothing?

Comment: @AntiDrondert no, Set contrato = Workbooks.Open(path) is working perfectly, it is setting contrato as the workbook I need

Comment: @YowE3K But i'm actually opening a third workbook that wasn't opened yet, and it only sets "nothing" when that sub is called by another sub from another workbook, that's what is making me crazy, still couldn't solve it : /

Comment: Sorry for answering only now, currently i'm managing a few projects so I have to divide them along the week

Comment: I managed to replicate the behaviour.  (I was originally having troubles even saving the workbook that opened another workbook in its `BeforeSave` event, until I realised that that only worked if you closed the newly opened workbook after it was opened.)  It looks like it might be a "bug" (or, at least, "unexpected behaviour").  Microsoft probably didn't expect anyone to be opening workbooks in a `BeforeSave` event.

Comment: @YowE3K sorry, didn't understand what you meant, i should close the contract, after opening the calendar? (that would be a problem to me : / because i needed to pass some information from the contract to the calendar but could manage another way to do it if it is the only solution). Just to be clear, which workbook are you referring with newly opened?

Comment: My comment was only meant to reflect that I could replicate your issue.  (The bit within my first set of parentheses was just reflecting my frustrations at creating an equivalent bit of code to your "Contract_beforeSave()" - because I originally didn't have a statement in that code to close the equivalent of your calendar workbook, and without that it wasn't letting me save the equivalent to your contract workbook, and therefore I couldn't get to the stage of creating the equivalent of your  reservations workbook.  But once I got it all sorted out I replicated the issue.)

Comment: And I have no idea how to fix the issue :(